# could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.xmlgregoriancalendar

Tags: java, xml, calendar

I am using web services(a custom/tailor made service for the component) to send and receive information. The request is being formed properly and I am also getting a response. However, during the the mapping of the response to  actual DTO, I am getting the following error:

```
could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.xmlgregoriancalendar
```

There are some calednar date form in the response, but I am not sure, why it is not able to initialize xmlgregoriancalendar class. I run it on my local with stubs, and it give me no problems at all.

any adivse would be helpful...Thanks in advance

Complete Stack Trace is as follows:

```
FindOrderController :: Exception encountered :: OrderRef :: 1185130652 :: UserId :: null : com.bt.collaboration.order.web.controller.FindOrderController-(340) 
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl 
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:144)
        at $Proxy489.querySimplifiedOrder(Unknown Source)
        at com.bt.collaboration.customer.client.mcso.McsoSyncPortClientImpl.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(McsoSyncPortClientImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bt.custc.logging.performance.OutboundLoggingInterceptor.invoke(OutboundLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy490.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(Unknown Source)
        at com.bt.collaboration.customer.service.OrderServiceImpl.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(OrderServiceImpl.java:65)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bt.custc.logging.performance.OutboundLoggingInterceptor.invoke(OutboundLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at com.bt.netc.frameworks.throttle.ThrottleInterceptorImpl.invoke(ThrottleInterceptorImpl.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:89)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy498.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bt.custc.logging.performance.OutboundLoggingInterceptor.invoke(OutboundLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy498.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:307)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:182)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:149)
        at com.bt.custc.logging.performance.OutboundLoggingInterceptor.invoke(OutboundLoggingInterceptor.java:109)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:171)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
        at $Proxy499.findHeavyOrderByOrderRef(Unknown Source)
        at com.bt.collaboration.order.web.controller.FindOrderController.handleRequestInternal(FindOrderController.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:875)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:807)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:571)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:511)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.bt.netc.frameworks.filters.FilterProxyImpl.doFilter(FilterProxyImpl.java:83)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:236)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.obtainContent(SiteMeshFilter.java:129)
        at com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter.doFilter(SiteMeshFilter.java:77)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at com.bt.collaboration.order.web.filter.PropertySetupFilter.doFilter(PropertySetupFilter.java:36)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
        at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
        at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Unmarshalling Error: Could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl 
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:771)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:623)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.io.DataReaderImpl.read(DataReaderImpl.java:128)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.DocLiteralInInterceptor.handleMessage(DocLiteralInInterceptor.java:190)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:671)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2177)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2057)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1982)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:47)
        at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:188)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:66)
        at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:637)
        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
        at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:236)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:483)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:309)
        at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:261)
        at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:73)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:124)
        ... 83 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl
        at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.DatatypeFactoryImpl.newXMLGregorianCalendar(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:583)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl.RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl$12.parse(RuntimeBuiltinLeafInfoImpl.java:662)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.reflect.TransducedAccessor$CompositeTransducedAccessorImpl.parse(TransducedAccessor.java:247)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.LeafPropertyLoader.text(LeafPropertyLoader.java:65)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.text(UnmarshallingContext.java:515)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.processText(StAXStreamConnector.java:339)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.handleEndElement(StAXStreamConnector.java:217)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StAXStreamConnector.bridge(StAXStreamConnector.java:186)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:368)
        at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:347)
        at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBEncoderDecoder.unmarshall(JAXBEncoderDecoder.java:749)
        ... 102 more
```

Comment: what type of web service it is? Is it JAX-RPC/WS? can you please add complete stack trace?

Comment: @UVM updated the comment with the stackTrace

Answer (score 1):

I also got this error: `NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.xerces.jaxp.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendarImpl`

Here is how I fixed it. Add in weblogic.xml this line:

```
{prefer-web-inf-classes}true{/prefer-web-inf-classes}
```

By default it's false.

This fix tells me there are jar version conflicts. But I have no idea exactly which jars in what folder that cause the conflicts.